# Popping noise when piping audio into a vitual mic debian

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, debian, sox

I have a pipe module with the command `pactl load-module module-pipe-source source_name=VirtualMic file=/tmp/virtualmic format=wav rate=44100 channels=2`

I want to use SoX to play a sound file into it. I am doing this with `sox "example.wav" -t wav - > /tmp/virtualmic`

I have tried piping the audio using ffmpeg, to the same result, and to confirm that it is not my computer speakers or the file, playing the file in audio programs such as vlc does not include a popping sound.

The number of channels and the sample rate are both identical, and other then the pop the audio plays normally

Comment: Though I have no clue how you might fix it, it sounds like you have a clock sync error. Is there anyway to force a clock master & slaves?

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was a simple issue, without the package `libsox-fmt-all` installed, i believe sox was playing the header of the file as well as the file itself. along with that, it seems i needed to change `-t wav` to `-t raw`. after installing the package and changing the option, the pop ceased.